# Session Start not 'starting'

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

This problem is really giving me a hard time. I have 4 files, one for DB config, the other for login page, 3rd for login-processing and lsat one for the redirect after successful login)
 This is my db-connect.php:

```
<?php

        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "dbroot";
        $password = "dbpassword";
        $dbname = "dbname";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if (!$conn) {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        ?>
```

the form in my user-login.php:

```
<form action="includes/login-process.php" id="login" class="formoid-metro-black" style="background-color:transparent;font-size:14px;font-family:'Open Sans','Helvetica Neue','Helvetica',Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;color:#FFFFFF;max-width:400px;min-width:150px; float:right;" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><div class="title"><h2>Log In</h2></div>
            <div class="element-input"><label class="title">Username<span class="required">*</span></label><input class="large" type="text" name="username" required="required"/></div>
            <div class="element-password"><label class="title">Password<span class="required">*</span></label><input class="large" type="password" name="password" value="" required="required"/></div>
            <div class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In"/></div></form><script type="text/javascript" src="forms/sign-up-form_files/formoid1/formoid-metro-black.js"></script>
```

The login-process.php:

```
<?php include ("db-connect.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);

  $encrypt = md5($password);

  $userquery = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE `user-username`='$username' AND `user-password`='$password'";

  $run = mysqli_query($conn,$userquery); 

  if(mysqli_num_rows($run)>0){

    $_SESSION['username']=$username;
    ?>
    <script>alert('Login successful.')</script>
    <script>window.open('../user-profile.php','_self')</script>
    <?php
  }
  else {
    ?>
    <script>alert('Username or Password Incorrect.','_self')</script>
    <script>window.open('../user-login.php','_self')</script>
    <?php

  }
}


?>
```

And in my login page, after i successfully log in, proven by the script alert being successful, however, as the user-profile.php opens (where I put a session_start() on top), it directly runs the condition inside the if statement, ignoring the fact that i already successfully logged in. 
This is my user-profile.php:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
      <?php  
      session_start();
      if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        ?> 
        <script> alert('Please Log-in first.','_self')</script>
        <?php include_once('user-login.php'); 
      }
      else {
        $first_name= $_SESSION['fname'];
        $first_name= ucfirst($first_name);
        ?>
   //rest of my code
```

The code above should run what's inside the else statement, but instead i keep getting the alert to login first. (Just ignore the $firstname codes, I want to get it for output below). Does any of you have any idea about this? If so, pleeeease help me. Thank you!

Comment: Did you set the value for `$_SESSION['username']`?

Comment: yes refer to my login-process.php code

Comment: Are you sure you want to disclose your real database username and password to the public?

Comment: it's fine its only for educational purposes

Comment: EVERY SCRIPT that want to use the SESSION must do a `session_start();` at the top of that script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your login-process.php, you must `session_start()` first before setting values to session variables.

Answer (score 1):

you are accessing session directly without declaring the session. User `session_start()` before accessing session variables and you may use `session_close()` once you are done accessing them.